# Couldn't figure out the error at printing custom timestamp in shell script using date?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I am trying to manipulate timestamps using date in shell script. My code is this

```
echo $(date -d '+10 mins' +%s%N)
```

This will print time 10 mins from current time in nanoseconds

> 1554242194228787268

When i move the echo statement inside a for loop to do a custom action based on the loop variable.

```
for repi in `seq 1 2`;
do
    lp_incr=$((repi*10))
    n_incr='+'$lp_incr' mins'
    echo $(date -d $n_incr +%s%N)
done
```

Getting error like this

> date: extra operand '+%s%N'

Remove that extra operand won't help me to view date alone

```
for repi in `seq 1 2`;
do
    lp_incr=$((repi*10))
    n_incr='+'$lp_incr' mins'
    echo $n_incr
    echo $(date -d $n_incr)
done
```

Again getting different error

> +10 mins 
>   date: the argument 'mins' lacks a leading '+';

$n_incr have the '+'still it throws an error.

It seems like i miss something in this. Entire motive is generate timestamp in nano seconds for some interval.
 Thanks in advance for all suggestions or alternate approaches.

Comment: See: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) Short answer: almost always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
echo $(date -d $n_incr +%s%N)
```

`$n_incr` is [expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to

```
echo $(date -d +10 mins +%s%N)
```

Note that `+10 mins` is not a single argument, but two.

The fix is to quote the argument:

```
echo $(date -d "$n_incr" +%s%N)
```

You can also omit `$n_incr`:

```
echo $(date -d "+$lp_incr mins" +%s%N)
```